# writing and reading vectors in math.net

Tags: c#, mathnet-numerics

Math.Net has the data package that allows reading and writing matrices. For a Matrix X, it is possible to write it to a stream using:

```
DelimitedWriter.Write<double>(stream, X);
```

and read it with

```
X = DelimitedReader.Read<double>(stream);
```

However, if Y is of type Vector, how do you read and write it?

Comment: From the [source code](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics-data/blob/master/src/Text/DelimitedWriter.cs) it doesn't seem like `DelimitedWriter` has this built-in.  Could you convert your vector to a column matrix with [`ToColumnMatrix()`](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra/Vector%601.htm#ToColumnMatrix) and write that, the later read as a matrix and convert to back to a vector with [`Column(0)`](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra/Matrix%601.htm#Column)?

Comment: Though honestly at least the [`Write()`](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics-data/blob/master/src/Text/DelimitedWriter.cs#L131) method looks so simple you could just do it yourself.

Comment: Your solution makes sense although I am still surprised that there is no established way to do that. Converting to a matrix will work but to do it right you need to verify dimensions.